# Using regexp to convert $(5.20) to -5.20

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm trying to convert `$(5.20)` to `-5.20` using regular expressions, but can't seem to figure out how to use regular expressions. Could someone please help me to resolve this issue? I need to remove the dollar sign and only accept digits with a maximum of 1 decimal point ie do not accept `5.2.0`, but only `5.20`. Also, the `$` at the beginning is optional and there could be multiple `$` as well.

Example of what I started with:

```
^\((\d)*\)$ - does not work

-$1
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this regex

```
^\$\((\d+\.\d+)\)$
```

Your replacement should already be fine. This regex expects at least one digit before and after the decimal point.

The problem with your regex is, that it will only match if there is no decimal point at all. Also you don't check for the `$` character. And lastly, if this `$(5.20)` is not your full string, than you should leave out the anchors at the beginning and at the end:

```
\$\((\d+\.\d+)\)
```

If you want to match numbers without decimal points, too, then you can make the dot and the second repetition optional:

```
\$*?\((\d+\.?\d*)\)
```

Comment: If not all numbers have decimal points, you can put a `?` after the `\.` and use `*` instead of the second `+`.

Comment: From his question I assumed they always have a decimal point, but I'll add it to the answer!

Comment: I had to add a minor tweak to your regex testing for multiple /optional $'s revised ^\$*?\((\d+\.\d+)\)$

Comment: Ah okay, I didn't know that the number of `$` was variable or that they are even optional. When asking regex questions please provide an extensive list of examples that match and that don't match. Also, if my answer solves your problem, please consider accepting it ;)

Comment: second revision incorporating optional decimals ^\$*?\((\d+(\.)?(\d+)?)\)$

Comment: Unfortunately I missed it in my requirements, but thanks for helping me. I would consider posting my most current revision since it handles all issues. Thank you

Comment: Your version also matches `$(5.)`. Have you tried the last version in my answer?

Comment: well yeah, that depends on your scenario and whether you want to consider it as a number or not (which is why I recommend the list of examples ^^). I just wanted to make sure you are aware of it.